# Mounting Gluster Volumes

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, glusterfs, amazon-route53

I have created Hosted Zone with 2 IP addresses of Gluster Cluster, both IP are returned by dig. After mounting Gluster, I cannot ls mount point as it takes long time. `mount` shows me it's mounted, but `df` doesn't.

Finally, I have this: ls: cannot access /mnt/storage: Transport endpoint is not connected.
But if I mount it with the one of the IP, no problem - volume contents is accessible

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

GlusterFS: 3.2.6

Log: http://pastie.org/private/2jgp4h1hnqgzych3djtg

I have can telnet storage from client - ports are open.

Comment: Instead of editing your title/answer, it's appropriate to answer your own question and accept that answer. Please give more details than "There was a DNS issue." when you do. This community is for more than just the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Private / Public DNS issue - misconfiguration. Resolved.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OP, it was a DNS issue. He didn't provide any additional detail.